# Is there any better way to do the data migration?

Tags: mysql, migration, database-migration

I have written couple of methods to retrieve data from LDap and put it into MySql database. I put those methods in a Listener, so that it executes while deploying the War.

Now this is a one time action. That means, I have to take all the data from Ldap and put those into the MySql DB, and then work on the database tables. I have nothing to do with the LDap data farther.

Is there any better way to do the data migration thing? Since it is a one time work, and once the database is created successfully, there is no need of these methods.

Please Suggest!
Thanks. :)

Comment: I meant, better than putting the methods in the Listener. I don't want those codes to execute every time I deploy War.

Answer (score 0):

For migration exercises, look into the Open Source Pentaho Data Integration tool (PDI, or commonly known as Kettle).

There is a *slight* learning curve, but it's easy to use, and you'll have it forever.